# getting text of a parent tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the " Fruit, Veg & Flowers " text with BeautifulSoup but what I get is the composition of the text of the div and the one that I want :
this is my code that I've tried :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
page=requests.get(" https://groceries.asda.com/product/grapes/asda-refreshing-sweet-seedless-red-grapes/1000076345132")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
data=soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'breadcrumb__current breadcrumb__current--bold','data-auto-id':'selectedBreadcrumb'}).get_text()
data2=soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'asda-link asda-link--primary breadcrumb__link','data-auto-id':'linkBreadcrumbName'})
for i in data2:
    print(i.get_text())
```

this is the output :

```
breadcrumb Fruit, Veg & Flowers /
breadcrumb Fruit /
breadcrumb Grapes /
breadcrumb Grapes
```

**this is the HTML pattern :**

```
<a class="asda-link asda-link--primary breadcrumb__link" data-auto-id="linkBreadcrumbName" href="/cat/fruit-veg-flowers/1215686352935" target="_self"><div aria-live="" class="visually-hidden">breadcrumb</div> Fruit, Veg &amp; Flowers <span aria-hidden="true">/</span></a>
```

So I wanna get rid of the "breadcrumb" text

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below.

```
for i in grocery_input.split("\n"):
    print(i.replace("breadcrumb", "").strip(" "))
```